# OpenLayers Workshop missing ol.js library

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

At the first step in workshop we try to create a basic map.

Here is the code for a map.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/ol/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 256px;
        width: 512px;
      }
    </style>
    <title>OpenLayers example</title>
    <script src="node_modules/js-yaml/lib/loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My Map</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: 'Global Imagery',
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
              url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms',
              params: {LAYERS: 'nasa:bluemarble', TILED: true}
            })
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          projection: 'EPSG:4326',
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 0,
          maxResolution: 0.703125
        })
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

After run this code, i suppose to view this map

https://openlayers.org/workshop/fr/basics/map.html

But, i have this two errors messages

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vay5e.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaqMl.png)

First of all i am suprised that in the line code of tutorial there not the ol.js library yet we can see that the ol function which is used to display on the map.

Then when i import the missing library i get this error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uusTW.png)

Comment: Looks like the french translation is out of date (at least it is different from the english version)

Comment: The French version is very old compared with the latest English version.  Either use the hosted ol.js and ol.css (or download them) as in https://openlayers.org/download/ with the French examples, or use the English examples.